# Loop with pagination only showing two pages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

i am last junior in wordpress and want to create `**pagination**` with wp_query but i get just 2 pages however i have 8 posts and display 2 per page 
--i searched alot about that in different websites and didnt find answer

```
<?php //GET POSTS
            $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
            $arr=array(
             'author'         =>the_author_meta('id'),
             'posts_per_page' => 2,
             'paged'          =>$paged,
            );

            $special_query= new WP_Query($arr);//SPECIAL QUERY

            if($special_query->have_posts()){//check if there is posts or no
                while($special_query->have_posts()){
                    $special_query-> the_post();
            /*content*/
            ?>
```

[pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWhYz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'author'=>the_author_meta('id'),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 
);
$loop = new WP_Query($query);

if( $loop->have_posts() ):
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
       //postcode
    endwhile;
endif;

$big = 9999; // need an unlikely integer
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on a template? Try this code and let me know if it works

```
<?php 

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'author' =>the_author_meta('id'),
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$special_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if($special_query->have_posts()){
    while($special_query->have_posts()){
        $special_query-> the_post();
            echo get_the_title() . "<br>";
    }
}
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $special_query->max_num_pages
) );
```

Comment: have you saved your permalink with post name?